# rotate nohup out file (nohup.log)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logrotate, nohup

is there a 'native' way where i can rotate nohup out file ?

Answer (score 2):

Check this article:  http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/solaris-l/nohup-files-rotation-when-process-is-running-639605

Comment: thanks looks good - i had something similar in mind - to connect input to output via a pipe but this confirms.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [script](https://serverfault.com/questions/189477/rotate-logs-of-a-dumb-non-interactive-application/189880#189880) I wrote to solve a similar problem.