# Rotating logs generated by a process that logs to stdin

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate, cronolog

I have a long running process, that writes its log file to `stdout`. I would like to save this output to different files, automatically maintain these files (like deleting/archiving the old ones), without restarting the main process.

On solution would be to send the output to a file (`process > log.txt`), and use `logrotate` on it, but `logrotate` needs to restart the program, which is not possible.

The other one is to pipe the output to `cronolog` (`process | cronolog`), but in this case older files won't get deleted / archived, meaning I have to make a program that will do the maintenance for me.

The best would be to be able to use both utilities, because with `cronolog` I don't need to restart the process, and `logrotate` will maintain the old log files exactly as I want. Is there a way to get these two programs to work with each other? If not, what is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: This http://serverfault.com/questions/189477/rotate-logs-of-a-dumb-non-interactive-application/189880#189880 probably answers your question

Comment: [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/) and [the journal](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-journal.html) should be able to fix this when they'll be available in production. systemd will redirect `stdout` to the journal and the journal will rotate the logs when needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Multilog](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from DJB's [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) can do (almost) exactly what you are asking. The only downside that I am aware of is that not many distributions carry a package for [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

If you are not managing your application with `svc` (part of the daemontools) you will have to find a way to pipe the output to a command like

```
multilog t s1048576 n100 ./my_log_directory
```

This translates to:

- `t`: insert a tai64n timestamp (that can be translated to readable time with `tai64nlocal`)
- `s1048576`: rotate the log file when it grows to 1MiB
- `n100`: keep no more than 100 rotated files
- `./my_log_directory`: anything starting with `.` or `/` - write the log to that directory

The log that is written will have the filename `current`, and when multilog rotates the log, it will be renamed to `@<tai64n timestamp>.s` where the filename shows the time when the file was rotated. The extension can be `.s` if the file was safely flushed, or `.u` if it may have been truncated.

For more info, just check the links.

### Update:

[svlogd](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) from [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/index.html) is a replacement for multilog with similar command line usage.

[s6-log](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/index.html) is another fork with more features and compatible command line usage.

Comment: Seems like the command I'm searching for. Fortunately it's available under Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/daemontools