# Rotating a nohup.out logfile

Tags: linux, logrotate, nohup

There are a few questions on how to rotate the output file generated by `nohup`.  Most of the answers say to use `logrotate` with the `copytruncate` option.

However this does not actually work -- when the rotation occurs, it creates the rotated logfiles ok but the original file is not actually truncated and further log output continues to be appended.

This also occurs if I don't use `nohup` and just run `myscript.py >>myscript.log` (so basically `copytruncate` seems completely useless).

What's the "right" way to do this?  (If custom script is required, either Bash or Python is preferred.)

Comment: Copytruncate should work. However, the right way to do it is described in lain answer because copytruncate may be responsible of small data loss.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to code `myscript.py` so that it writes to a log file rather than stdout and reacts to signals by closing  and reopening it's log file.

Comment: Ok, granted.  But I want to know how to do it without doing that.  (The script is a third party one and is large and difficult to modify.)

Comment: @Miral If copytruncate really doesn't work, use a [named pipe](http://serverfault.com/questions/189477/rotate-logs-of-a-dumb-non-interactive-application/189880#189880)

Comment: Use your script in pipeline: `3rd_party_script.py | your_script 3rd_party_script.log`